# What's the translation of “flame trench" in French?

Tags: traduction

What's the translation of “flame trench" in French?

“Flame trench" in English can be defined as [follows](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2979/1111):

> The Flame Trench is the big hole used to manage the flame from the rocket initially. Here's a shot of the [Space Shuttle's Flame Trench](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/shuttle/launch/Flame-trench-deflector.html):

[image]

[image]

Google translate translates "flame trench" as "tranchée de flammes", but Googling "tranchée de flammes" returns fewer than 100 results which makes me wonder whether there exists a more common phrase. No luck on https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=flame+trench either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not very well known but the right name is [**carneau**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carneau).